# Give user permission to create/delete particular file?

Tags: unix, file-permissions

Is it possible to give a user permission to create/delete a file at a certain path, but not to modify other files in the same directory?.

I'm using Ansible to provision a CentOS 6.4 box. I'd like to make certain playbooks that non-root users can run, to make relatively safe changes like refreshing the httpd.conf file from a template. The users have write permission on that file. But when Ansible copies a file, it needs to delete and re-create it, so it needs write access to the parent directory. I'd rather not give them access to delete other files in the directory.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the sticky bit on a directory will permit users to create new files in that directory. They can also rename and delete their own files, but not other users' files. This is used on `/tmp` and a few other directories.

Using `chmod 1775 /path/to/directory` would allow users in the group of that directory to create new files in that directory, but they cannot delete each other's files.